# Kubernetes vSphere Setup IPV4 issue

Tags: kubernetes, ipv4, vsphere

I'm following the [kubernetes VM setup guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/vsphere/).  After uploading the vmdk successfully, the kubernetes-master VM is started up, but it has no IPV4 address.  Therefore, the next step in the script fails because it tries to SSH to the kubernetes master to run the setup of the nodes. Other VMs created via the web client correctly receive an IP4 address, but any VM created from govc does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a customer's setup and it turns out they did not have DHCP setup on the selected network, therefore, no IP.